# uploadCrashlyticsMappingFile task fails because of mapping.txt?

Tags: android, proguard

This gradle task keeps failing because it says it cannot find mapping.txt file and as a result i am unable to build APK. I understand that this file is related to pro-guard but interestingly it works some of the time. The task fails randomly and i have no clue what is causing this. Kindly advise.

> mapping.txt (No such file or directory)